# What happened Ghatotkach children Anjanaparvan and Meghavarna?

Tags: mahabharata

What happened to family tree of Ghatotkach?
We know about Barbarika's story .

But what about the other two children Anjanaparvan, Meghavarna, and their family tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anjanaparvan was killed by Ashwatthama in Mahabharata war:

Ashwatthama The son of Drona then slew that son of Bhima's son, viz., Anjanaparvan, cased in an iron coat of mail, even as Mahadeva had slain in days of yore the Asura Andhaka. Beholding his mighty son slain by Aswatthaman, Ghatotkacha, coming unto the son of Drona... ~ [Mahabharata: Drona Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07152.htm)